# blur event doesn't trigger at first attempt

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, .post

I'm trying to update the DOM based on the value entered in a text box.

HTML:

```
<input id="event-name" type="text"/>
```

JQUERY:

```
$('#event-name').on('blur',function(){
  $.post("scripts/add-team-support.php",{eventName : eventName},function(minAndMaxString){
  //my code here
  });
});
```

this works on the first blur in Chrome. When I tried it in opera, mozilla and edge it doesn't worked on the first attempt.

It worked when I added this before the jquery.

```
$("#event-name").focus();
$("#event-name").blur();
$("#event-name").focus();
```

I did this to make the first $.post call to occur when the page opens.

Why is this problem happening?
How to solve this in a proper way?
Please help!

Comment: try keyup event

Comment: keyup, keydown, keypress produced the same problem. I tried them too.

Comment: `blur` event is a bit strange choice. Why not listen for `change` event which has almost the same meaning?

Comment: Tried it now. It didn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It often happens with elements across browsers that consequent events do not work when binding an event to them through ID or class. The following solution should help you:

```
$(document).on('blur','#event-name', function(){
  $.post("scripts/add-team-support.php",{eventName : eventName},function(minAndMaxString){
  //my code here
  });
});
```

Alternatively, you could use `keyup` event. You can do so following:

```
$(document).on('keyup','#event-name', function(){
  var eventName = $(this).val();
  $.post("scripts/add-team-support.php",{eventName : eventName},function(minAndMaxString){
  //my code here
  });
});
```

Also, using `-` in IDs is not a good approach. Rather, either stick to `camelCase` or `underscore_format` of naming convention.

Comment: The blur event didn't worked but the keyup event worked as it makes the first call when I type the first letter. I will use this. I changed the blur to keyup in my code.

Comment: Great! Also, make sure you handle events for keys like 'backspace', in which case, you already have the data! Also, if the answer helped you, please mark it as accepted answer!

Comment: I will see to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

```
var lazyTriggerEvent = function(id,event,callback){
    var searchTrigger=null;
    $("#"+id).bind(event,function(){
        var text = $.trim($(this).val());
        clearTimeout(searchTrigger);
        searchTrigger = setTimeout(function(){
            callback(text);
        },500);
      })
   };
//use keyup event
lazyTriggerEvent("event-name","keyup",function(){})
```